# Got allows a redirect to a UNIX socket

Tags: npm-scripts, npm-audit

```
# npm audit report

got  <11.8.5
Severity: moderate
Got allows a redirect to a UNIX socket - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-pfrx-2q88-qq97
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install nodemon@1.3.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/got
  package-json  <=6.5.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of got
  node_modules/package-json
    latest-version  0.2.0 - 5.1.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of package-json
    node_modules/latest-version
      update-notifier  0.2.0 - 5.1.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of latest-version
      node_modules/update-notifier
        nodemon  >=1.3.5
        Depends on vulnerable versions of update-notifier
        node_modules/nodemon
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @robertklep I'm getting the vulnerability warning while auditing my react app. I already tried `npm audit fix --force` but it gives me more vulnerabilities due to the older version of react-scripts. My question is how to fix this warning?

Answer (score 2):

Editing **package.json** should do the trick:

1. For **NPM** users

> ```
> "overrides": {
>   "got": "^12.1.0"
> }
> ```

2. For **YARN** users

> ```
> "solutions": {
>   "got": "^12.1.0"
> }
> ```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this removed the vulnerability but broke my jest test cases

Comment: This is not a solution.  Got semver is no joke, practically the whole API changed between v9 and v10.  You can't just drop in a newer version and expect anything to work, you have to update whatever dependency is requiring it.  If you used Got directly, you have to check the v10 release notes and (extensively!) refactor your consuming code.

Answer (score 0):

From the advisory - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-pfrx-2q88-qq97, this might give you a more complete response.

```
"overrides": {
    "got@<11.8.5": "11.8.5",
    "got@>=12.0.0 <12.1.0 ": "^12.1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your package directly depends on a pinned, [old version of package-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/package-json?activeTab=versions).  The 6.x version has not been updated in 5 years.  You need to upgrade to a supported version of package-json, which will pull in a version of `got` which has fixed the vulnerability you're asking about.

ETA: I may have read your dependency tree backwards, in which case the problematic direct dependency is `nodemon`.  Same guidance would apply, try to update the direct dep rather than `got`.  `npm why got` can be helpful here.